# CodeIgniter doesn't recognize templates

Tags: php, templates

Once I create PHP application and didn't open application a long time the views are terrible, so PHP doesn't recognize my template which I used. I get only HTML structure of application. 
I want to complete this application, but there aren't template and It look very bad. 
**Here is my code:**

**header.php**

```
*<html>
    <head>
        <title>Car Sharing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/darkly/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/style.css">
    </head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url();?>pages/view">Car Sharing</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts/create">Postavi Oglas</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/create">Postavi Kategoriju</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories">Kategorije</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts/index">Sve voznje</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>about">O nama</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>contact/index">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/logout">Log out</a></li>

        <?php endif;?>


        <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/register">Registracija</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/login">Login</a></li>
        <?php endif ;?>



        <li class="dropdown">
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container">

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('user_registred')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_registred').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('post_created')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('post_created').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('post_updated')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('post_updated').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('category_creted')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('category_created').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?> 

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('post_deleted')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('post_deleted').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?> 

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->session->flashdata('login_failed').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?> 

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('user_loggedin')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_loggedin').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?> 

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('user_loggedout')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_loggedout').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?> 

<?php  if($this->session->flashdata('category_deleted')):?>
<?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('category_deleted').'</p>'?>
<?php endif;?>*
```

**footer.php**

```
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is what I get when I run application

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV9Jw.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4L1W.jpg)

Any comments ?

Comment: I think your css not working properly. you can check through ctrl+u and then click on style.css link then you will see your css load properly or not.

Comment: I also think that css is problem, but in folder with assets I have one style.css and stylesheet.css that why I dont know which one I used :/

Comment: try using stylesheet.css on the page.

Comment: @AlamDarji I am trying but nothing changed

Comment: remove the <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/darkly/bootstrap.min.css"/> and add this link:
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you guys, I found mistake. 
The mistake was my link: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/darkly/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
The bootstrap was delete theme which I used, so I have to change thema